# Referencing a past query in a loop SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to intersect two or more results from a query from a for loop

My code takes in strings from the command line and checks the database for movies with matching actors

movie database

id | name

actor database

id | name

acting

movie_id | actor_id
i.e.

```
inp = sys.argv[1]

query = 
'''
SELECT m.name 
FROM movie m
    JOIN acting ag on m.id = ag.movie_id
    JOIN actor a on a.id = ag.actor_id
WHERE a.name = ?
'''

cur.execute(query, (inp,))
for tup in cur.fetchall:
    print(tup)
```

This program would get all the movies with actor called David

```
./program "David'

The Secret Life of Pets
The Big Short
Concussion
A Most Violent Year 
Baggage Claim
Skyfall 
Drive 
Albert Nobbs 
The Book of Eli 
Shine a Light 
The Bourne Ultimatum 
The Simpsons Movie
```

I want to extend my program to take in multiple arguments, taking in multiple names of actors, where the actors act in the same movie.

Possible code?

```
for index in range(len(sys.argv - 1)):
    # insert code here
```

I think I should use an intersection of the outputs of the queries, but I don't know how to do that.

This is the output of movies that both Albert and David

```
./program "Albert" "David"
A Most Violent Year 
Baggage Claim 
The Simpsons Movie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to construct a query that returns the common movies of all actors that you pass as arguments:

```
query = """
SELECT m.name 
FROM movie m
JOIN acting ag on m.id = ag.movie_id
JOIN actor a on a.id = ag.actor_id
WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || a.name || ',%'
GROUP BY m.id, m.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = ?
"""
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query, (','.join(sys.argv[1:]), len(sys.argv)-1))
for tup in cur.fetchall():
    print(tup[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you explain a few things please. I don't understand why there are so many commas in the where clause, and why it is the variable like a.name, not a.name like the variable, though I'm not sure that matters. Also, why do we group by both m.id and m.name

Comment: @MichaelQiao This query passes the app's arguments as a comma separated string, say `"Albert,David"` (this is what `','.join(sys.argv[1:])` does) and with the operator `LIKE` it checks if that string is *LIKE* the name (contains the name) of an actor. I did the grouping on both m.id and m.name just in case there are 2 movies with the same name (this is possible). If there is such a case then you should also select m.id and not just m.name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So because we used like instead of =, should the code work the same with ./program "alb" "dav"? I tried that but it doesn't output the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelQiao no this does not work when there are multiple partial names passed. It would work only for your original query for 1 partial name: `WHERE a.name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'`.

Comment: Yep, I got it! This is probably going to differ completely, but how would you implement the code to take in multiple partial names for the actors?

Comment: @MichaelQiao this is a different requirement and if it is implemented in SQLite it would require a recursive query, if it is implemented in Python it would require a loop. In any case for a new requirement you should ask a new question.